# linux command to list details (like PID, VID) of connected devices to the serial port(s) (like RS232) of a computer

Tags: linux, hardware, serial-port

with USB port we can search Product ID (PID) and Vender ID (VID) of connected devices by using **`lsusb`** command. Is there a similar way to get PID and VID if the same device is connected to **RS232 serial port**

Comment: RS232 predates Plug'n'Play by several decades.  There's no way detecting what you actually connected to the port.

Comment: You would probably have to interface with the device(s) that are connected on the RS232 port themselves directly or use protocol specific discovery functions to see what is living on the other side of the port. But either way you need to go up the network stack to get that info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

USB has a standardized method to learn device information including PID and VID. This information is available by the enumeration phase and takes place of the control endpoint. This is possible because there is an additional protocol on top of the raw data signals.

The RS232 serial port is much simpler and does not have similar functionality defined. Data is data, and its interpretation is up to the user/ program using that port. There is no VID nor PID defined for a RS232-connected device such as a printer.